# Using $q in Angular JS to pass navigator geo JSON from factory to controller

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise, factory-method, geospatial

This code is used to get the users location and deliver it as a resource to the controller. The aim is to have this data shared across multiple controllers in the application. So far this does deliver the data as a parameter of the `then()` method on the promise.  Is this pattern a suitable way of sharing a resource which is delivered through a promise? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
angular.module('geolocation', [])
.factory('geolocation', function ($q, $window) {
    return {
        getLocation: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                deferred.resolve(position);
            }); 

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

angular.module('nearestLocationCtrl', [
    'geolocation'
])
.controller('NearestLocationCtrl', ['$scope', 'geolocation', function ($scope, geolocation) {
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use resolve feature of ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) or ngRoute. 
Promise will be resolved and injected into controller automatically, service and controller will be nicely decoupled. 
Using ui-router code would look like this:

```
app.controller('NearestLocationController', function($scope, location) {
}

$stateProvider.state('locationState', {
      resolve: {
         location: function(geolocation){
            return geolocation.getLocation();
         }
      },
      controller: 'NearestLocationController'
})
```